# Django Channel Error wile building a chat application

Tags: python, django, channel, django-channels, asgi

I am trying to build a chat application using Django and channel.
But I am getting not able to get my view file (room.html)
My main project name is "techChat" and I have a app called "chat"
I ma trying all this code from :- https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html
When i enter the lobby name i get page not found. I also have the asgi file if you take a look at my file structure whose img is below.

Help!

My Code

views.py :-

[image]

chat/urls.py (App urls file):-

[image: chat/urls.py (App urls file)]

techChat/urls.py (main project urls file)

[image: techChat/urls.py (main project urls file)]

My room.html template file:-
[image]

My index.htm file template
[image]

[image: This Is How My File Structure Is]

My Index Page output :-
[image]

Now when I Enter the "lobby" in the text box I get Page Not Found Error!
[image]

Comment: In techChat/urls.py, have you tried putting "chat/" (with a forward slash) rather than "chat" as the first argument to path() on line 7?

Comment: I guess that this is not the error but you should have a template folder and in it you should have your chat folder and there the templates should located. Also please post the code as text and not as pictures.

Answer (score 0):

> ## techChat/urls.py
>
> from django.contrib import admin from
> django.urls import path, include
> urlpatterns = [
> path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
> path('', include('chat.urls')), ]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).